# Горизонтальная прокрутка таблицы всегда сверху

Tags: html, bootstrap, прокрутка, responsive

Имеется огромная `html` таблица с горизонтальным скроллом, сделанным с помощью бутстраповского `.table-responsive`. Таблица длинная, и чтобы сдвинуть ее влево-вправо приходится крутить до конца вниз, до скролла, что не совсем удобно. Имеется ли возможность прикрепить скролл к низу окна браузера, чтобы был всегда на виду?
P.S. Футера нет, таблица завершает экран.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать ещё один элемент со скролом и в него вносить скрипт:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZXnqM/324/

```js
$(function() {
 $('#w-scroll .scroll').css({width: $('.search-table').outerWidth()});
  $('#w-scroll').scroll(function() {
   $('.search-table-outter').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    $(this).css({left: $(this).scrollLeft()});
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($('.search-table').offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 22){
       $('#w-scroll').css({top: 0, bottom: 'auto'});
    }else if($('.search-table').offset().top + $('.search-table').outerHeight() > $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()){
     $('#w-scroll').css({top: $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - $('.search-table').offset().top + 22, bottom: 'auto'});
    }else{
      $('#w-scroll').css({top: 'auto', bottom: 0});
    };
  });
  $('#w-scroll').each(function() {
   if($('.search-table').offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 22){
       $('#w-scroll').css({top: 0, bottom: 'auto'});
    }else if($('.search-table').offset().top + $('.search-table').outerHeight() > $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()){
     $('#w-scroll').css({top: $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - $('.search-table').offset().top + 22, bottom: 'auto'});
    }else{
      $('#w-scroll').css({top: 'auto', bottom: 0});
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.search-table-outter {border:2px solid red; overflow-x:hidden;position:relative;}
.search-table{table-layout: fixed; margin:40px auto 0px auto;}
.search-table, td, th{border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #777;}
th{padding:20px 7px; font-size:15px; color:#444; background:#66C2E0;}
td{padding:5px 10px; height:35px;}
#w-scroll {position:absolute;width:100%;height:auto;overflow-x:scroll}
#w-scroll .scroll {height:1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search-table-outter wrapper">
 <table class="search-table inner">
  <tr>
   <th>Col1</th>
   <th>Col2</th>
   <th>Col3</th>
   <th>Col4</th>
   <th>Col5</th>
   <th>Col6</th>
   <th>Col7</th>
   <th>Col8</th>
   <th>Col9</th>
   <th>Col10</th>
  </tr>
        <tr>
   <td><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason  </a></td> 
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
            <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
  </tr>
              <tr>
   <td><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason  </a></td> 
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
            <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
  </tr>
              <tr>
   <td><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason  </a></td> 
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
            <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
   <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  <div id="w-scroll"><div class="scroll"></div></div>
</div>
```